# where should I create user sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop an automation site (ASP.NET web app) which may have up to hundreds of users at once. I'm almost finished creating the site, but I KNOW I HAVE MADE some mistakes and one of them is using public static variables at codebehind pages instead of using sessions for each user, now when user A changes a setting in a page, USER B also views the page exactly the same way that user A views it!, rather than viewing the page in default state. I have a question:
where should I declare my sessions for each user? when users login, I create a session for each one, and this is the only session that I've used so far:

```
Session.Add("userid" + myReader["ID"].ToString(), "true");
```

should I create other necessary sessions right here? i.e. at login time? for instance I have declared some public static variables at a page responsible for viewing DB:

```
        public static string provinceid = "0";//0 means all
    public static string branchid = "0";
    public static string levelid = "0";
    public static string groupid = "0";
    public static string phrase = "";
```

should I declare one session for each of them at login time? or can I declare them at startup of each page?

thanks

Comment: You should not add the actual UserID-Value to the Session-Key since the session is already user-independtly.  For example: `Session.Add("UserID", myReader["ID"].ToString());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Session` object is unique per user already - you do not need to "create" it.

Using static variables would cause these items to be shared across *all* threads (so all users). These should probably be converted to session variables.

Comment: yeah, that right but I want to know where should I declare them? should I declare all public static variables as sessions after user login? i.e. after Session.Add("userid" + myReader["ID"].ToString(), "true");? is the right place?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet - You shouldn't have statics at all. And it doesn't matter when you declare them. They will be part of that user session, logged in or not. If you only want these to be set after login, then that's when you need to set them.

Comment: @Ali_dotNet - Again, if they only need to exists during login time, then yes.

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: But Session values don't need to be removed categorical, because if the Session times out, they will be disposed automatically(default 20 minutes).http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx Don't mix the user's authentication state with session, they are independent. Hence the session can timeout while the user is still logged in and the user can logout but the session still exists.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of your statics, you would just do something like this:

```
Session["provinceid"] = "0";
Session["branchid"] = "0";
Session["levelid"] = "0";
Session["groupid"] = "0";
Session["phrase"] = "";
```

As Oded mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856241/861565), the Session is already unique to the user, so no need for using the "Add" method.

Whenever you are done with this information (user logs out, etc), you can use the `Session.Clear()` method, which removes all the keys and values from the `Session` object.

Comment: thanks but how can I destroy the sessions created by Session["a"] = "b"?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet You can use `Session.Clear()`.  This clears all the keys and values from the `Session` object.  I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I KNOW I HAVE MADE some mistakes and one of them is using public
>   static variables at codebehind pages

You are right about that. That's a pretty bad thing to do on a web app.

You don't need to create a user Session since it's already created automatically when the user hits your website the first time. What you need in order to use Session the way you intend to is something like this:

```
//Store value 
Session["Key"]=myValue;


//retrieve field
var myValue = Session["Key"];
```

You can do this on any page you want since Session is a global object; it doesn't need to be done on the login page, but whenever you need to store anything that's specific to the user.